# 'Encapsulate Field' tool for a PHP IDE

Tags: php, ide, code-generation

Does anybody know an PHP IDE that features a tool to encapsulate private variables, as Visual Studio does for C#/VB/etc? In fact any IDEs that support PHP and include code-generation tools would be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes and no ;)

There are IDEs that support code generation of getter and setter methods. For example the commercial [Zend Studio for Eclipse](http://www.zend.com) and the free [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com) with PHP Plugin. In fact this is a bit different to the encapsulation in C#, as you won't get this:

```
private String _name;



    public String Name

    {

        get { return _name; }

        set { _name = value; }

    }
```

but something this:

```
<?php

class sample 
{
protected $myMember;

public function getMyMember()
{
    return $this->myMember;
}

public function setMyMember($myMember)
{
    $this->myMember = $myMember;
}
}
?>
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Regards,
Mario